# Windows 11: how to customize the emoji keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, emoji-keyboard

Is it somehow possible to customize the Windows 11 emoji keyboard? Maybe through some registry keys? (I liked the Windows 10 emoji keyboard so much better)

### 1. Default Tab

- How to change the default tab when opening the keyboard? Not showing the "most recently used" but the "Emoji" tab directly?
- Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch the tabs? (I also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but it's not working and it's not really a shortcut to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> ten times)

[image: emoji keyboard]

### 2. Emoji Size

How to change the default size of the emojis? They are displayed pretty big: I can't only see four lines of them! This makes it hard so find the one that you need, especially as there are now hundreds variants of the same emoji?

[image: emoji keyboard] [image: emoji keyboard]

Comment: I'm after the same answers... Did you find anything since ?

Comment: @Neoweiter unfortunately not... typing out the emoji name seems to be the fastest option but therefore you need to know how to call the expression of an emoji. You can find out by hovering over the emoji with your mouse.